# Add product search form from Select category and attribute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How To Add Woo commerce   custom search form there are two search form first category select box and another a custom  product attribute
in second select show only those attribute there are alienable in this selected  category

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom product search form with using `get_product_search_form` hook in your `function.php` file.

You can add your own field inside this function to create custom search form something like this:

```
function woo_custom_product_searchform( $form ) {

    $form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/'  ) ) . '">
        <div>
            <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __( 'Search for:', 'woocommerce' ) . '</label>
            // ADD YOUR OWN FIELD HERE.......
            <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__( 'Search', 'woocommerce' ) .'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
        </div>
    </form>';

    return $form;

}
```

This way you can override your WooCommerce Search form.

You can also set your custom query to fetch products from your own custom field.

Please follow this [link](http://jamescollings.co.uk/blog/extending-woocommerce-search-query-include-custom-fields/) for more information about how to set custom search query using custom fields.

I hope this will helpful for you.

Thanks.